# Unity ads testing

Tags: ios, iphone, unity-game-engine, chartboost

I am making a unity app for iOS and implementing chartboost. How do I test my app on my iPhone before fully sending it to the app store. Besides the unity remote bc i don't think the ads work on there. Can I test my ads and app on Xcode after building my project?

Answer (score 0):

Yea, in some region Chartboost doesn't show their ads. Well, to test your ad

- Go and login to the [Chartboost Dashboard](https://dashboard.chartboost.com/) -> Expand `All Apps` -> Verify either you have implemented SDK successfully or not, by observing GREEN TICK WITH IOS. Like this,

[image: Step1]

If it is so, then turn on `Testing Mode`.

- Go to your app.
- On left panel, in App Settings -> Basic Settings, you can see `Test Mode` radio button, enable it for at least 2 hours. It should be like this,

[image: Step2]

2 hours is because approx after half an hour may be you will get a test ad.

**Remember:** Do disable test mode before making it live.